# adding custom ggplot legend to dashed lines and confidence bands

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble setting a custom legend for confidence bands and dashed lines. This is my graph so far.

```
di<-matrix(ncol = 3,nrow = 5) %>% as.data.frame()
colnames(di)<-c('group','estimate','SE')
di<-di %>% mutate(group=1:5,
                  estimate=c(0.5,9.6,13,15,23.1),
                  SE=14)

ggplot(di, aes(x=group, y=estimate)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(width=.5, aes(ymin=estimate-(1.647*SE), ymax=estimate+(1.647*SE)), colour="black") +
  xlab('Group') +
  ylab('Treatment Effect') +
  labs(title="GATE with confidence bands", 
       subtitle="Point estimates and confidence bands are derived using median of all splits") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(7.83,22.55), 
             linetype="longdash",
             col='darkred') +
  geom_hline(yintercept=15.19, 
             linetype="longdash",
             col='blue')
```

It looks like this:
[image]

However what I want it to look like is something like this, with the exact same legend:

[image]

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. As a general rule: If you want to have a legend you have to map something on aesthetics, e.g. move `color=...` into `aes()` for all four geoms
2. The desired color values can then be set via `scale_color_manual`
3. For the `geom_hline` we also have to pass `yintercept` as an `aes()` too. To this end these get something helper data frames with the desired values.
4. To fix the lines and shapes in the legend I make use of `guide_legend`'s `overide.aes` to remove the undesired points in the legend as well as removing the line for the point. Additionally I set the number of rows for the legend to 2.
5. The labels and the order of the layers can be set via the `labels` and the `breaks` argument of `scale_color_manual`
6. Move the legend in the topleft and get rid of the background fill for the legend and the keys via `theme` options.

```r
library(ggplot2)

di <- data.frame(
  group = 1:5,
  estimate = c(0.5, 9.6, 13, 15, 23.1),
  SE = 14
)

labels <- c(point = "Point", error = "Error", blue = "Blue", darkred = "Red")
breaks <- c("blue", "darkred", "point", "error")

ggplot(di, aes(x = group, y = estimate)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = "point"), size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(width = .5, aes(
    ymin = estimate - (1.647 * SE),
    ymax = estimate + (1.647 * SE),
    color = "error"
  )) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(
    point = "black",
    error = "black",
    blue = "blue",
    darkred = "darkred"
  ), labels = labels, breaks = breaks) +
  labs(
    title = "GATE with confidence bands",
    subtitle = "Point estimates and confidence bands are derived using median of all splits",
    x = "Group",
    y = "Treatment Effect",
    color = NULL, linetype = NULL, shape = NULL
  ) +
  geom_hline(
    data = data.frame(yintercept = c(7.83, 22.55)),
    aes(yintercept = yintercept, color = "darkred"), linetype = "longdash"
  ) +
  geom_hline(
    data = data.frame(yintercept = 15.19),
    aes(yintercept = yintercept, color = "blue"), linetype = "longdash"
  ) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
    shape = c(NA, NA, 16, NA),
    linetype = c("longdash", "longdash", "blank", "solid")
  ), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0, 1), 
        legend.justification = c(0, 1), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image]